# Python: df.to_sql with OperationalError 1046, 'No database selected and OperationalError 2005, "Unknown MySQL server hos

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pandas, sqlalchemy, backand

I want to change to another MySQL database (from backand) from my current one. So, I suppose it is about the way I set the database settings.

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pw@backands146367311ktcttuv7')
df_2.to_sql(name='KLSE', con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

it returns this error

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'backands146367311ktcttuv7' (0)")
```

When I use another settings,

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pw@bk-prod-us1.cd2junihlkms.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306')
df_2.to_sql(name='KLSE', con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

It returns this error

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1046, 'No database selected') [SQL: 'DESCRIBE `KLSE`']
```

Below is the MySQL database information provided

```
  Database Type:
    mysql
    Endpoint:
    bk-prod-us1.cd2junihlkms.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
    Database name:
    backands146367311ktcttuv7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to specify the database name in your DB URL after the port number, like this:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pw@bk-prod-us1.cd2junihlkms.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/backands146367311ktcttuv7'
```

Comment: although I have no error after I created the table, but when I search the database in backand.com, it said the tables was created with erros as there is no primary key. I use to create same database in db4free.net but with no issues. I do not understand why?

Comment: I am using sqlalchemy which is suppose to add primary key automatically